# How to understand the sigma types example from "Theorem Proving in Lean 4"?

Tags: lean4

In the Lean 4 book called "Theorem Proving in Lean 4" (https://lean-lang.org/theorem_proving_in_lean4/title_page.html), I don't understand a code example about cartesian product types in chapter 2 "Dependent Type Theory".

The example (which I have edited to keep only relevant information) is:

```
universe u v

def f (α : Type u) (β : α → Type v) (a : α) (b : β a) : (a : α) × β a :=
  ⟨a, b⟩

def h1 (x : Nat) : Nat :=
  (f Type (fun α => α) Nat x).2

#eval h1 5 -- 5
```

I would have written `h1` as below:

```
def h1 (x : Nat) : Nat :=
  (f Nat (fun α => α) x x).2
```

I don't understand why the first argument of `h1` has to be `Type` instead of the `Nat` concrete type since we told that the type of its first argument type is `(α : Type u)` i.e. `α` is a type like `Nat`. Don't we build pairs of naturals ?

After having read the comment of question [Non-trivial examples of dependent sum ($\Sigma$-types) in Lean?](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/778/2892), I understand that the first element of the pair has to be a type (and not a natural) which allows us to make the type of the second element depend on it. That brings two questions:

1. What is the role of universes `u` and `v` used in this example ? Is there an implicit hierarchy like `u < v` or `u + 1 = v` ? I think the concept of "universe" is not explained in the manual before meeting that example.
2. Could the type of the second element in the pair depend on a concrete value alone instead of a type ? Would it still be called a cartesian product dependent type ? See below.

```
def f' (_n : Nat) (β : Nat → Type v) (a : Nat) (b : β a) : (a : Nat) × β a := ⟨a, b⟩

def h1' (x : Nat) : Nat := (f Nat (fun _ => Nat) x x).2

#eval h1' 5 -- 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, there is a universe hierarchy. The role of universes is to let you manipulate types just like the elements of any other type, say `Nat`. So for instance, the `list` type family simply has type `Type -> Type`, without the need for a separate "type-level" quantification/function type like for polymorphic functions in OCaml for instance. The question then is "what is the type of `Type`?". If one goes the naïve way and asks that `Type : Type`, paradoxes ensue (an analog of [Russel's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) called [Girard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_U#Girard%27s_paradox)). The standard solution is to have a hierarchy of `Type`, `Type 0 : Type 1 : …`. But in practice, this is not very workable, as one wants to be more flexible. This is why most type-theoretic proof assistants implement a more relaxed approach, typically one where one uses variables for universe levels, together with a set of constraints, which ensures that there always exists an instantiation of the levels with integers in a sound way.
2. Yes, there is nothing forcing the first type to be `Type`. Your example is indeed still a cartesian product, albeit a slightly degenerate one (because the type of the second component does not depend on the first one). That way, you recover the usual non-dependent version of binary product. If you want a more interesting example, here is one

```
def g (b : Bool) : Type :=
  match b with
  | true => Nat
  | false => Bool

def h1'' (x : Nat) : Nat := (f Bool g true x).2

#eval h1'' 5
```

The function `g` really *computes* a type based on its argument.